# HtmlBeginForm post Model Empty

Tags: razor, model, controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I generate a list of divs with data from my model. I need to get the data from the selected divs. So my solution was to put html.beginform in for loop , so when one of the forms is submited i can get the post data. 
The Model :

```
   public class yDul
    {
        public List<Uc[]> u { get; set; }
        public matrixB matrixblg { get; set; }
    }

public class Uc
{
    public List<UcAk> Ay = new List<UcAk>();
    public List<UcUi> Ba = new List<UcUi>();
    public double NetTutar;
}
```

The HTML :

```
@for (int l = 0; l < Model.u.Count; l++)
{

    @using (Html.BeginForm("secilen", "U"))
    {
        <li class="liuc">
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.u[l][0].NetTutar)
            </div>
        </li>
    <input type="submit" value=@Resources.sec class="choose">
    }
}
```

When I do like this , the model is passed back NULL. It generated 50-60 list items , and there is actually close to 15-20 properties inside the li (I simplified it for easy of reading). How can I get the data that is on the selected form ?

Comment: You have exactly 1 `li` inside each of **50-60 forms**... I doubt this is what you intended as this will not even generate valid HTML. Can you provide your full HTML as the sample shown is obviously incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the only elements that are serialised out into the request body and posted back are

```
input
select
button
textarea
```

Since your loop only generates li tags, they don't get serialised.

To get your data back in, you can use hidden inputs to this

```
@for (int l = 0; l < Model.u.Count; l++)
{

    @using (Html.BeginForm("secilen", "U"))
    {
        <li class="liuc">
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.u[l][0].NetTutar)
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.u[l][0].NetTutar)
            </div>
        </li>
        <input type="submit" value=@Resources.sec class="choose">
    }
}
```

The other thing to be careful of is the fact that you are using an array, this might lead to problems with the model binder not binding up anything but the first entry

Read this post from Phil Haacked about how to fix that

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Comment: I changed my code to that , but now model is not null , m.u is there with 1 member but NetTutar is 0(not null '0') . What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: I found the error for that , it was that I didnt put {get; set;} to the properties